# Create a public spreadsheet which requires users click the "edit" button to mutate it?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I customize a public Google Spreadsheet like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0ArUrIhNliD7bdHVqSVBIQXVNU1lrazhYOXJGZUZvM0E&type=view&gid=0&f=true&sortcolid=-1&sortasc=true&rowsperpage=250)?

It needs users to click the "Edit" button so that they can edit:

[image: WA69166 question example]

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of "List view" that features in the previous version of Sheets. It is no longer supported in the new version; to the best of my knowledge, I think it has been more or less replaced by the "[Filter view](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en)" feature.

Comment: How can we make one then?